# When can my house owner see what websites I visited?

Tags: wifi

If I load a page for 2 seconds but it is still white and nothing is visible, will he still be able to see that I visited that URL?

Comment: If web traffic is being logged, then it doesn't matter how long you visited or what gets displayed.

Comment: Does that house owner have admin access to your computer or installed anything on it?  Are those sites secure (HTTPS) or not?

Comment: No its my private smartphone and I don't think it was https

Answer (score 1):

**OBS: This answer is considering you were accessing a HTTP (not HTTPS) website, through your browser without using any proxy or anonymous service like Tor.**

Lots of things happen before something is even shown in your screen:

1) *DNS requests and replies (to get the IP address of the website)*

2) *TCP packets stablishing a connection to the website server*

3) *HTTP packets exchanging requests and replies for files from that website (like .html files, images, and so on)*

After your browser receives those files, it can then display the final result on your screen.

If your house owner can see which websites you are accessing depends first on how hard he monitors the network traffic.

1) **WORST CASE SCENARIO:** He sniffs on every packet that runs through his network. In this case he can most likely see which websites you are accessing. In this really paranoid scenario, he might even have access to information you exchanged with this website (like passwords, or forms).

2) He has some Logging or Parental Control feature enabled on his router. In this case he could see which websites you are accessing, but wouldn't have much detail on what you are doing after you accessed them.

3) He just doesn't really care about the websites you access at all.

Now it's up to you to see which of those scenarios mostly fit your current situation.

What you can do to access your websites with a more ensured privacy is to use a Proxy or Tor. Making it simple: this will send your requests to a server through a encrypted tunnel and this server will be the one talking to the website. The server will then take the websites response back to you.

No security guru here, just an enthusiat, so feel free to correct my answer!

Answer (score -2):

I think your house owner would need a firewall with logging capability to see what sites you've visited.